Spring LDAP CommunicationException: simple bind failed on port 636 with certificate
I'm trying to connect to an LDAP server using Spring LDAP on port 636 with certificate. However, I'm facing this following error:
org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: ttldaps.test.intra:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: ttldaps.test.intra:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class LdapConfiguration {

  @Value("${authentication.test-ldap.root-pass}")
  private String rootPass;

  @Value("${authentication.test-ldap.root-cn}")
  private String rootCn;

  @Value("${authentication.test-ldap.base-dc}")
  private String baseDc;

  @Value("${authentication.test-ldap.provider-url}")
  private String providerUrl;

  @Value("${authentication.test-ldap.initial-context-factory}")
  private String initialContextFactory;

  @Value("${authentication.test-ldap.security-authentication}")
  private String securityAuthentication;

  @SneakyThrows
  @Bean
  public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl(providerUrl);
    contextSource.setContextFactory(Class.forName(initialContextFactory));
    contextSource.setBase(baseDc);
    contextSource.setUserDn(rootCn);
    contextSource.setPassword(rootPass);
    return contextSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
    return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
  }
}

And here is my application.properties with fake datas:
authentication.test-ldap.initial-context-factory=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
authentication.test-ldap.provider-url=ldaps://ttldaps.test.intra:636/
authentication.test-ldap.security-authentication=simple
authentication.test-ldap.base-dc=DC=test1,DC=test2
authentication.test-ldap.root cn=CN=test,OU=test,DC=test1,DC=test2
authentication.test-ldap.root-pass=test1234

@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    public Boolean disableSSLValidation() throws Exception {
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        }}, null);

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);

        return true;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module pageJacksonModule() {
        return new PageJacksonModule();
    }
}


Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?
How to fix the "java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present" error?

When I connect to the LDAP server on port 389 with TLS, it works fine, but I get the above error on port 636 with SSL. I will add a certificate under the resources but how can I solve this problem? (I want to manage application.properties)
Environment:

Spring Boot version: 2.x
Java version: 11

Any help or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
